# app crashes when passing object via intent

Tags: android, android-intent, serializable, jsonschema2pojo

I have a `RecyclerView` and onclicking any item I want to start an activity by sending the object corresponding to the item via intent. But app crashes when i try to send the object.
My Model class

```
public class ProductListDataModel {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("product_id")
@Expose
private Integer productId;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("manufacturer")
@Expose
private Object manufacturer;
@SerializedName("sku")
@Expose
private String sku;
@SerializedName("model")
@Expose
private String model;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;
@SerializedName("images")
@Expose
private List<Object> images = null;
@SerializedName("original_image")
@Expose
private String originalImage;
@SerializedName("original_images")
@Expose
private List<Object> originalImages = null;
@SerializedName("price_excluding_tax")
@Expose
private Float priceExcludingTax;
@SerializedName("price")
@Expose
private Float price;


@SerializedName("price_formated")
@Expose
private String priceFormated;
@SerializedName("rating")
@Expose
private Integer rating;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("attribute_groups")
@Expose
private List<Object> attributeGroups = null;
@SerializedName("special")
@Expose
private Float special;
@SerializedName("special_excluding_tax")
@Expose
private Float specialExcludingTax;
@SerializedName("special_formated")
@Expose
private String specialFormated;
@SerializedName("special_start_date")
@Expose
private String specialStartDate;
@SerializedName("special_end_date")
@Expose
private String specialEndDate;
@SerializedName("discounts")
@Expose
private List<Discount> discounts = null;
@SerializedName("options")
@Expose
private List<Option> options = null;

@SerializedName("minimum")
@Expose
private String minimum;
@SerializedName("meta_title")
@Expose
private String metaTitle;
@SerializedName("meta_description")
@Expose
private String metaDescription;
@SerializedName("meta_keyword")
@Expose
private String metaKeyword;
@SerializedName("seo_url")
@Expose
private String seoUrl;
@SerializedName("tag")
@Expose
private String tag;
@SerializedName("upc")
@Expose
private String upc;
@SerializedName("ean")
@Expose
private String ean;
@SerializedName("jan")
@Expose
private String jan;
@SerializedName("isbn")
@Expose
private String isbn;
@SerializedName("mpn")
@Expose
private String mpn;
@SerializedName("location")
@Expose
private String location;
@SerializedName("stock_status")
@Expose
private String stockStatus;
@SerializedName("stock_status_id")
@Expose
private Integer stockStatusId;
@SerializedName("manufacturer_id")
@Expose
private Integer manufacturerId;
@SerializedName("tax_class_id")
@Expose
private Integer taxClassId;
@SerializedName("date_available")
@Expose
private String dateAvailable;
@SerializedName("weight")
@Expose
private String weight;
@SerializedName("weight_class_id")
@Expose
private Integer weightClassId;
@SerializedName("length")
@Expose
private String length;
@SerializedName("width")
@Expose
private String width;
@SerializedName("height")
@Expose
private String height;
@SerializedName("length_class_id")
@Expose
private Integer lengthClassId;
@SerializedName("subtract")
@Expose
private String subtract;
@SerializedName("sort_order")
@Expose
private String sortOrder;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("date_added")
@Expose
private String dateAdded;
@SerializedName("date_modified")
@Expose
private String dateModified;
@SerializedName("viewed")
@Expose
private String viewed;
@SerializedName("weight_class")
@Expose
private String weightClass;
@SerializedName("length_class")
@Expose
private String lengthClass;
@SerializedName("shipping")
@Expose
private String shipping;
@SerializedName("reward")
@Expose
private Object reward;
@SerializedName("points")
@Expose
private String points;
@SerializedName("category")
@Expose
private List<Category> category = null;
@SerializedName("quantity")
@Expose
private Integer quantity;
@SerializedName("reviews")
@Expose
private Reviews reviews;
@SerializedName("recurrings")
@Expose
private List<Object> recurrings = null;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getProductId() {
    return productId;
}


private String isAddedWish = "0";

public String getIsAddedWish() {
    return isAddedWish;
}

public void setIsAddedWish(String isAddedWish) {
    this.isAddedWish = isAddedWish;
}

public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Object getManufacturer() {
    return manufacturer;
}

public void setManufacturer(Object manufacturer) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
}

public String getSku() {
    return sku;
}

public void setSku(String sku) {
    this.sku = sku;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public List<Object> getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(List<Object> images) {
    this.images = images;
}

public String getOriginalImage() {
    return originalImage;
}

public void setOriginalImage(String originalImage) {
    this.originalImage = originalImage;
}

public List<Object> getOriginalImages() {
    return originalImages;
}

public void setOriginalImages(List<Object> originalImages) {
    this.originalImages = originalImages;
}

public Float getPriceExcludingTax() {
    return priceExcludingTax;
}

public void setPriceExcludingTax(Float priceExcludingTax) {
    this.priceExcludingTax = priceExcludingTax;
}

public Float getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Float price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getPriceFormated() {
    return priceFormated;
}

public void setPriceFormated(String priceFormated) {
    this.priceFormated = priceFormated;
}

public Integer getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(Integer rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public List<Object> getAttributeGroups() {
    return attributeGroups;
}

public void setAttributeGroups(List<Object> attributeGroups) {
    this.attributeGroups = attributeGroups;
}

public Float getSpecial() {
    return special;
}

public void setSpecial(Float special) {
    this.special = special;
}

public Float getSpecialExcludingTax() {
    return specialExcludingTax;
}

public void setSpecialExcludingTax(Float specialExcludingTax) {
    this.specialExcludingTax = specialExcludingTax;
}

public String getSpecialFormated() {
    return specialFormated;
}

public void setSpecialFormated(String specialFormated) {
    this.specialFormated = specialFormated;
}

public String getSpecialStartDate() {
    return specialStartDate;
}

public void setSpecialStartDate(String specialStartDate) {
    this.specialStartDate = specialStartDate;
}

public String getSpecialEndDate() {
    return specialEndDate;
}

public void setSpecialEndDate(String specialEndDate) {
    this.specialEndDate = specialEndDate;
}

public List<Discount> getDiscounts() {
    return discounts;
}

public void setDiscounts(List<Discount> discounts) {
    this.discounts = discounts;
}

public List<Option> getOptions() {
    return options;
}

public void setOptions(List<Option> options) {
    this.options = options;
}

public String getMinimum() {
    return minimum;
}

public void setMinimum(String minimum) {
    this.minimum = minimum;
}

public String getMetaTitle() {
    return metaTitle;
}

public void setMetaTitle(String metaTitle) {
    this.metaTitle = metaTitle;
}

public String getMetaDescription() {
    return metaDescription;
}

public void setMetaDescription(String metaDescription) {
    this.metaDescription = metaDescription;
}

public String getMetaKeyword() {
    return metaKeyword;
}

public void setMetaKeyword(String metaKeyword) {
    this.metaKeyword = metaKeyword;
}

public String getSeoUrl() {
    return seoUrl;
}

public void setSeoUrl(String seoUrl) {
    this.seoUrl = seoUrl;
}

public String getTag() {
    return tag;
}

public void setTag(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
}

public String getUpc() {
    return upc;
}

public void setUpc(String upc) {
    this.upc = upc;
}

public String getEan() {
    return ean;
}

public void setEan(String ean) {
    this.ean = ean;
}

public String getJan() {
    return jan;
}

public void setJan(String jan) {
    this.jan = jan;
}

public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}

public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

public String getMpn() {
    return mpn;
}

public void setMpn(String mpn) {
    this.mpn = mpn;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getStockStatus() {
    return stockStatus;
}

public void setStockStatus(String stockStatus) {
    this.stockStatus = stockStatus;
}

public Integer getStockStatusId() {
    return stockStatusId;
}

public void setStockStatusId(Integer stockStatusId) {
    this.stockStatusId = stockStatusId;
}

public Integer getManufacturerId() {
    return manufacturerId;
}

public void setManufacturerId(Integer manufacturerId) {
    this.manufacturerId = manufacturerId;
}

public Integer getTaxClassId() {
    return taxClassId;
}

public void setTaxClassId(Integer taxClassId) {
    this.taxClassId = taxClassId;
}

public String getDateAvailable() {
    return dateAvailable;
}

public void setDateAvailable(String dateAvailable) {
    this.dateAvailable = dateAvailable;
}

public String getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(String weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public Integer getWeightClassId() {
    return weightClassId;
}

public void setWeightClassId(Integer weightClassId) {
    this.weightClassId = weightClassId;
}

public String getLength() {
    return length;
}

public void setLength(String length) {
    this.length = length;
}

public String getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(String width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public String getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public Integer getLengthClassId() {
    return lengthClassId;
}

public void setLengthClassId(Integer lengthClassId) {
    this.lengthClassId = lengthClassId;
}

public String getSubtract() {
    return subtract;
}

public void setSubtract(String subtract) {
    this.subtract = subtract;
}

public String getSortOrder() {
    return sortOrder;
}

public void setSortOrder(String sortOrder) {
    this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getDateAdded() {
    return dateAdded;
}

public void setDateAdded(String dateAdded) {
    this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
}

public String getDateModified() {
    return dateModified;
}

public void setDateModified(String dateModified) {
    this.dateModified = dateModified;
}

public String getViewed() {
    return viewed;
}

public void setViewed(String viewed) {
    this.viewed = viewed;
}

public String getWeightClass() {
    return weightClass;
}

public void setWeightClass(String weightClass) {
    this.weightClass = weightClass;
}

public String getLengthClass() {
    return lengthClass;
}

public void setLengthClass(String lengthClass) {
    this.lengthClass = lengthClass;
}

public String getShipping() {
    return shipping;
}

public void setShipping(String shipping) {
    this.shipping = shipping;
}

public Object getReward() {
    return reward;
}

public void setReward(Object reward) {
    this.reward = reward;
}

public String getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public void setPoints(String points) {
    this.points = points;
}

public List<Category> getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(List<Category> category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public Integer getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public Reviews getReviews() {
    return reviews;
}

public void setReviews(Reviews reviews) {
    this.reviews = reviews;
}

public List<Object> getRecurrings() {
    return recurrings;
}

public void setRecurrings(List<Object> recurrings) {
    this.recurrings = recurrings;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ProductListDataModel{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", productId=" + productId +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", manufacturer=" + manufacturer +
            ", sku='" + sku + '\'' +
            ", model='" + model + '\'' +
            ", image='" + image + '\'' +
            ", images=" + images +
            ", originalImage='" + originalImage + '\'' +
            ", originalImages=" + originalImages +
            ", priceExcludingTax=" + priceExcludingTax +
            ", price=" + price +
            ", priceFormated='" + priceFormated + '\'' +
            ", rating=" + rating +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", attributeGroups=" + attributeGroups +
            ", special=" + special +
            ", specialExcludingTax=" + specialExcludingTax +
            ", specialFormated='" + specialFormated + '\'' +
            ", specialStartDate='" + specialStartDate + '\'' +
            ", specialEndDate='" + specialEndDate + '\'' +
            ", discounts=" + discounts +
            ", options=" + options +
            ", minimum='" + minimum + '\'' +
            ", metaTitle='" + metaTitle + '\'' +
            ", metaDescription='" + metaDescription + '\'' +
            ", metaKeyword='" + metaKeyword + '\'' +
            ", seoUrl='" + seoUrl + '\'' +
            ", tag='" + tag + '\'' +
            ", upc='" + upc + '\'' +
            ", ean='" + ean + '\'' +
            ", jan='" + jan + '\'' +
            ", isbn='" + isbn + '\'' +
            ", mpn='" + mpn + '\'' +
            ", location='" + location + '\'' +
            ", stockStatus='" + stockStatus + '\'' +
            ", stockStatusId=" + stockStatusId +
            ", manufacturerId=" + manufacturerId +
            ", taxClassId=" + taxClassId +
            ", dateAvailable='" + dateAvailable + '\'' +
            ", weight='" + weight + '\'' +
            ", weightClassId=" + weightClassId +
            ", length='" + length + '\'' +
            ", width='" + width + '\'' +
            ", height='" + height + '\'' +
            ", lengthClassId=" + lengthClassId +
            ", subtract='" + subtract + '\'' +
            ", sortOrder='" + sortOrder + '\'' +
            ", status='" + status + '\'' +
            ", dateAdded='" + dateAdded + '\'' +
            ", dateModified='" + dateModified + '\'' +
            ", viewed='" + viewed + '\'' +
            ", weightClass='" + weightClass + '\'' +
            ", lengthClass='" + lengthClass + '\'' +
            ", shipping='" + shipping + '\'' +
            ", reward=" + reward +
            ", points='" + points + '\'' +
            ", category=" + category +
            ", quantity=" + quantity +
            ", reviews=" + reviews +
            ", recurrings=" + recurrings +
            '}';
}
```

}

I tried to send the object via intent as the following method

```
private ArrayList<ProductListDataModel> productList;

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("data",productList );
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

But this causes the app to crash. The error I get on crashing is

```
"UncaughtException:     
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4800)"
```

I have created the model class by using jsonschema2pojo online.
Any one please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Implement _ProductListDataModel_ with _Serializable_ or _Parcable_

Comment: [How can I make my custom objects Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-parcelable)

Comment: Also _productList_ should not be empty

Comment: not working , again crashes with error "UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.myapp.test.model.model_product_list.ProductListDataModel)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable"

Answer (score 1):

do these changes

implement `Serializable` in your model class.

```
 public class ProductListDataModel  implements Serializable{

    //your rest code 

    }
```

Comment: not working,getting error as "UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.myapp.test.model.model_product_list.ProductListDataModel)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable"

Answer (score 1):

You must implement with `parcelable`, once you implemented it, you have to add implemented methods in your model class, which automatically generates by android studio.

And then send your object in intent like this way

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,CallFragmentOrActivity.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data", productList);
    getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    getActivity().finish();
```

And then get your `parcelable` object in your called activity or fragment

```
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        yourProductListObject = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("data");
    }
```

I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable` in you `ProductListDataModel`

for eg:

```
public class ProductListDataModel implements Serializable{ 


// your code

}
```

or By using Parcelable :

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class ProductListDataModel implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;


    protected ProductListDataModel(Parcel in) {
        if (in.readByte() == 0) {
            id = null;
        } else {
            id = in.readInt();
        }
    }

    public static final Creator<ProductListDataModel> CREATOR = new Creator<ProductListDataModel>() {
        @Override
        public ProductListDataModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ProductListDataModel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ProductListDataModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ProductListDataModel[size];
        }
    };

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProductListDataModel{" +
                "id=" + id +

                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        if (id == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
            dest.writeInt(id);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: not working. app crases again. "UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.myapp.test.model.model_product_list.ProductListDataModel)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable"

Comment: when implementing parcelable, recycleradapter binding not working.